# Oracle - Count of number of days a value has changed

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I have a requirement to write a query in Oracle as shown in the screenshots below. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance. Vadi.

[image]

[image]

Table with sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE fee_check (
  trans_date DATE,
  fee1 NUMBER(6,3),
  fee2 NUMBER(6,3)
);

INSERT INTO fee_check(trans_date, fee1, fee2) VALUES (to_date('18/04/2022','dd/mm/yyyy'), 0.74, 0.87);
INSERT INTO fee_check(trans_date, fee1, fee2) VALUES (to_date('19/04/2022','dd/mm/yyyy'), 0.75, 0.87);
INSERT INTO fee_check(trans_date, fee1, fee2) VALUES (to_date('20/04/2022','dd/mm/yyyy'), 0.75, 0.87);
INSERT INTO fee_check(trans_date, fee1, fee2) VALUES (to_date('21/04/2022','dd/mm/yyyy'), 0.73, 0.87);
INSERT INTO fee_check(trans_date, fee1, fee2) VALUES (to_date('22/04/2022','dd/mm/yyyy'), 0.73, 0.87);
INSERT INTO fee_check(trans_date, fee1, fee2) VALUES (to_date('23/04/2022','dd/mm/yyyy'), 0.73, 0.87);
INSERT INTO fee_check(trans_date, fee1, fee2) VALUES (to_date('24/04/2022','dd/mm/yyyy'), 0.73, 0.87);
INSERT INTO fee_check(trans_date, fee1, fee2) VALUES (to_date('25/04/2022','dd/mm/yyyy'), 0.76, 0.87);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What is your expected output if you had `2022-04-26, 0.74, 0.87` and the `fee1, fee2` combination is repeated in a non-contiguous date ranges? Do you want to get two rows for that combination with the day counts `2` and `1` respectively (in which case the accepted answer does not give the correct solution) or do you want to get only a single row with a day count of `3` (in which case the accepted answer does that)?

Comment: Hi MT0, Thanks for your comment. The given solution is correct for the given data. But your point is valid. This was the sample data I was given to work with. I would want 2 rows of data with different counts. I will have to check your scenario with additional data. Thanks again. Regards Vadi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution of your problem

```
SELECT MIN(trans_date) trans_date, COUNT(*) DayCount, fee1, fee2 
FROM fee_check 
GROUP BY fee1,fee2
ORDER BY trans_date
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only count consecutive rows (rather than aggregating non-consecutive groups with the same fee values together) then, from Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to do row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   fee_check
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY trans_date
  MEASURES
    FIRST(trans_date) AS trans_date,
    COUNT(trans_date) AS day_count,
    FIRST(fee1) AS fee1,
    FIRST(fee2) AS fee2
  PATTERN (same_fees+)
  DEFINE same_fees AS fee1 = FIRST(fee1) AND fee2 = FIRST(fee2)
)
```

Or, in earlier versions, you can use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT MIN(trans_date) AS trans_date,
       COUNT(*) AS day_count,
       MIN(fee1) AS fee1,
       MIN(fee2) AS fee2
FROM   (
  SELECT f.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY trans_date) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fee1, fee2 ORDER BY trans_date) AS grp
  FROM   fee_check f
)
GROUP BY grp
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE fee_check (trans_date, fee1, fee2) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-04-18', 0.74, 0.87 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-19', 0.75, 0.87 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-20', 0.75, 0.87 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-21', 0.73, 0.87 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-22', 0.73, 0.87 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-23', 0.73, 0.87 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-24', 0.73, 0.87 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-25', 0.76, 0.87 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-26', 0.75, 0.87 FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: there is an extra row added at the end that has the same `fee1` and `fee2` values earlier in the data set.*

Both output:

> | TRANS_DATE | DAY_COUNT | FEE1 | FEE2 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-04-18 00:00:00 | 1 | .74 | .87 |
> | 2022-04-19 00:00:00 | 2 | .75 | .87 |
> | 2022-04-21 00:00:00 | 4 | .73 | .87 |
> | 2022-04-25 00:00:00 | 1 | .76 | .87 |
> | 2022-04-26 00:00:00 | 1 | .75 | .87 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=16dd9bf94d4d8f01dbda70f54459062c)*

Comment: Hi MT0, Thanks a lot for the solution. It is much appreciated. I think you read my mind :-). I will check your solution. Thanks a lot again. Regards Vadi.

Comment: Hi MT0. The match recognize solution works perfectly. I think I will use that. Thanks a lot again for taking the trouble. Much appreciated. Regards